# Cannot import weka in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, weka

I want to write a code with Weka using IntelliJ.
I downloaded the Weka.JAR file from their website and extracted it in the src folder of my main class.
So, after creating my project, inside the src folder is something like this :
[image: Inside src folder]

and inside the weka folder above is this (downloaded and extracted from their site ) :
[image: Inside weka folder]

and my code does these imports : (This is a template file that I must complete. I'm new to weka)

```
import weka.associations.AssociationRule;
import weka.associations.AssociationRules;
import weka.associations.BinaryItem;
import weka.associations.FPGrowth;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
```

Each of these imports leads to a file with `.class` ending, not `.java` and I haven't seen any of these kinds of imports. for example, inside the `associations` directory where I want to import two files with names `AssociationRule` and `AssociationRules` is something like this :
[image: Inside associations folder]

and of course, IntelliJ marks the last filenames red. It finds packages and folders but not the files. Maybe because they have the `.class` suffix instead of the `.java` suffix? I tried to change their suffix to `.java` but they crashed and their characters were no longer valid. Also, IntelliJ issue didn't resolve.

by the way, I downloaded the weka.JAR file from [here](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/downloading_weka/) under the other platforms
[image: IntelliJ cannot find specified files although their names exist]

Comment: why exactly didn't you download weka-src.jar ?

Comment: @Stultuske I did. I downloaded a zip with two ( or maybe more ) JAR files. I just saw a youtube film and he used weka.JAR. So I should use weka-src.JAR? and extract it in my src folder?
I'm working on a code and they did these imports from weka.

Comment: Please check this article about adding JAR as a library: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks it fixed the issue